# Where do I collect Outerworld Challenge rewards?

Tags: lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13

I have Outerworld Services turned on, and have posted a few messages during the various challenges (PR events, basically). The news updates on the menu screen indicate that challenges 1 & 2 have been completed, and that I should be able to find an NPC whose name is @LRFF13 in blue rather than the usual white, but I've seen no sign of this NPC.

Where can they be found? Do I have to be on at least a certain day? Do they appear only in New Game Plus?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have Outerworld Services turned on and you are connected to the internet, eventually NPCs with blue names should start popping up in the various city and village areas in the game. They are not limited to being Humans, they can be things such as dogs and other animals as well. Talking to these NPCs will display a small message and a picture/screenshot of another players game, including the chance to buy an item off them.

The NPC named @LRFF13 spawns randomly, and often I've played a session and never seen the NPC spawn at all, whereas other times I've seen the NPC multiple times in different places throughout the world.

Good luck finding the NPC in your game, I'm sure you'll find it eventually!